# Database good system decoupling point?

Tags: decoupling, system-design

We have two systems where system A sends data to system B.   It is a requirement that each system can run independently of the other and neither will blow up if the other is down.  The question is what is the best way for system A to communicate with system B while meeting the decoupling requirement.

System B currently has a process that polls data in a db table and processes any new rows that have been inserted.

One proposed design is for system A to just insert data into system b's db table and have system B process the new rows by the existing process.  Question is does this solution meet the requirement of decoupling the two systems?  Is a database considered part of a system B which might become unavailable and cause system A to blow up?

Another solution is for system A to put data into an MQ queue and have a process that would read from MQ and then insert into system B's database.  But is this just extra overhead?  Ultimately is an MQ queue any more fault tolerant than a db table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, database sharing is a close coupling and not to be preferred except possibly for speed purposes. Not only for availability purposes, but also because system A and B will be changed and upgraded at several points in their future, and should have minimal dependencies on each other - message passing is an obvious dependency, whereas shared databases tend to bite you (or your inheritors) on the posterior when least expected. If you go the database sharing route, at least make the sharing interface explicit with dedicated tables or views.

There are four common levels of integration:

1. Database sharing
2. File sharing
3. Remote procedure call
4. Message passing

which can be applied and combined in various situations, with different availability and maintainability. You have an excellent overview at the [enterprise integration patterns site](http://www.eaipatterns.com/).

As with any central integration infrastructure, MQ should be hosted in an environment with great availability, full failover &c. There are other queue solutions which allow you to distribute the queue coordination.

Answer (score 3):

Use Queues for communication.  Do not "pass" data from System A to System B through the database.  You're using the database as a giant, expensive, complex message queue.

Use a message queue as a message queue.

This is not "Extra" overhead.  This is the best way to decouple systems.  It's called Service Oriented Architecture (SOA) and using messages is absolutely central to the design.

An MQ queue is far simpler than a DB table.

Don't compare "fault tolerance" because an RDBMS uses huge (almost unimaginable) overheads to achieve a reasonable level of assurance that your transaction finished properly.  Locking.  Buffering.  Write Queues.  Storage Management.  Etc.  Etc.

A reliable message queue implementation uses some backing store to keep the queue's state.  The overhead is much, much less than an RDBMS.  The performance is much better.  And it's much, much simpler to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server I would do this through an SSIS package or a job (depending on the number of records and the complexity of what I was moving). Other databases also have ETL solutions.  I like the ETL solution becasue I can keep logs of what was changed and what errors were processed, I can send records which for some reason won't go to the other system (data structures are rarely the same between two databases) to a holding table without killing the rest of the process. I can also make changes to the data as it flows to adjust for database differences (things like lookup table values, say the completed status in db1 is 5 and it is 7 in db2 or say db2 has a required field that db1 does not and you have to add a default value to the filed if it is null). If one or the other servver is down the job running the SSIS package will fail and neither system will be affected, so it keeps the datbases decoupled as using triggers or replication would not.